# A problem with interpolation

Tags: interpolation, data

Consider the following [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1niozvyc5klkjva/Data.txt?dl=0) (~2 mb), `Data.txt`.

I am going to import it, interpolate (to obtain a function `NevAll[ma,ga]`), and then to obtain a region where `NevAll` is larger than 2.3. This is how I do this:

```
NevTab = Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "Data.txt"}], 
   "Table"];
Nev1[ma_, ga_] = 
  Interpolation[{#[[1]], Log10[#[[2]]], #[[3]] + 10^-99} & /@ NevTab, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1][ma, Log10[ga]];
Nev2[ma_, ga_] = 
  Interpolation[{#[[1]], Log10[#[[2]]], #[[4]] + 10^-99} & /@ NevTab, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1][ma, Log10[ga]];
Nev3[ma_, ga_] = 
  Interpolation[{#[[1]], Log10[#[[2]]], #[[5]] + 10^-99} & /@ NevTab, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1][ma, Log10[ga]];
Nev4[ma_, ga_] = 
  Interpolation[{#[[1]], Log10[#[[2]]], #[[6]] + 10^-99} & /@ NevTab, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1][ma, Log10[ga]];
NevAll[ma_, ga_] = 
  Nev1[ma, ga] + Nev2[ma, ga] + Nev3[ma, ga] + Nev4[ma, ga];
Sensitivity[Nev_] := Block[{},
  RegionSensitivity = 
   Quiet[RegionPlot[
     Nev[10^ma, 10^ga] >= 2.3, {ma, Log10[0.2], 
      Log10[2.2]}, {ga, -12., -3.}, PlotPoints -> 200]];
  {10^#[[1]], 10^#[[2]]} & /@ 
   Partition[
    Flatten[Cases[Normal@RegionSensitivity, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]],
     2]
  ]
SensitivityAll = Sensitivity[NevAll];
```

However, the region is not smooth:

```
ListLogLogPlot[SensitivityAll, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

My opinion is that it suffers from interpolation, which introduces these "squares" and jumps at both the lower and upper bounds of the region. Could you please tell me a way to fix it?

Comment: I think it is all in your data. Interpolation with InterpolationOrder->1 does nothing else than linearly interpolate. Now look e.g. at NevTab[[4]]. It contains 4 points with a value of 0. The Log of it is -Infinity. No wonder that you get a peak

Comment: @DanielHuber : To interpolate zeros, I may replace them with say 10^-99 and make a logarithm. However, the peaks (that are not an artifact and follow from the data) prevent me from doing this: the region becomes discontinuous.